# Display the data returned by 'getData.php' in the DIV 'table'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, getjson

I need to display the data returned by 'getData.php' in the DIV 'table'. How can I do this? The problem is that I cannot access 'data' elements in DIV 'table'.

PS I'm using jquery data table. Therefore $.get('modules/drawTable.php', function(data) {...}) did not work properly (style was missed).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadData();
});

function loadData() {
   $.getJSON(
        'modules/getData.php',
        function(data) {    
               var list = list.flights;                   
               $('#table').html(list); // Also I tried this: $('#table table').html(list)
        }
       );             
    }

<div id="table" style="display:none;">
     <table>
        // display rows from 'data' array
        //<?php foreach ($data as $row):
        //  $var1=$row['var1'];....
     </table>
</div>
```

**getData.php**

```
$list = array();
// fill the array
echo json_encode(array('flights' => $list));
var_dump($list);
```

die();

Comment: Did you mean `$('#table table').html(data);` instead?

Comment: did you check the json data output ? ?

Comment: @coosal: sure. getData returns json data.

Comment: can you show the json output ? ?

Comment: @coosal: Pls see the updated thread. Var_dump prints the array in Firebug. So, the array is not empty.

Comment: So by now the output must be displayed in the `#table` div as you edited your syntax for `json` data output . .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question right, but have you tried using .after and .append functions to fill the table with your data?

Btw - if you are not sure what is the server response, use `console.log(data);` - it's great debugging - at least in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: console.log(list) printed out the content of the array. So array is not empty. How to use .after and .append?